# Why is there an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, regex, exception, illegalargumentexception, regex-group

My program is printing a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` whenever I run it. It replaces certain patterns with different expressions including groups from the pattern it matched. It replaces a portion of the patterns, then this error comes up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:713)
    at RealReadFile.main(RealReadFile.java:93)
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;

public class RealReadFile {
    private static final String fileName = "KLSadd.tex";
    private Scanner myFile = null;

    public RealReadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (myFile == null)
            myFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }

    public RealReadFile(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (myFile != null)
            myFile.close();
        myFile = new Scanner(new File(name));
    }

    public boolean endOfFile() { 
        return !myFile.hasNext(); 
    }

    public String nextLine() {
        return myFile.nextLine().trim();
    }

    public int times(String oneline){
            int count = 0;
            Pattern cpochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\(([^\\)]+)\\)_\\{?([^\\}]+)\\}?)");
            Matcher pochhammer = cpochhammer.matcher(oneline);
            while (pochhammer.find()) {
                count++;
            }   
        return count;
    }

    public void multipleChar(RealReadFile file){
        while (!file.endOfFile()) {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            int count=file.times(line);
            while(count>0){
                Pattern cpochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\(([^\\)]+)\\)_\\{?([^\\}]+)\\}?)");
                Matcher pochhammer = cpochhammer.matcher(line);
                if (pochhammer.find()) {
                    //System.out.println(line);
                    line = pochhammer.replaceFirst("\\\\pochhammer{"+ pochhammer.group(2) + "}{" + pochhammer.group(3) + "}");
                    count--;
                    }
                if(count==0)
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
    }

    public void singleChar(RealReadFile file){
        while (!file.endOfFile()) {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            int count=file.times(line);
            while(count>0){
            Pattern cpochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\(([^\\)]+)\\)_(.))");
            Matcher pochhammer = cpochhammer.matcher(line);
            if (pochhammer.find()) {
                //System.out.println(line);
              line = pochhammer.replaceFirst("\\\\pochhammer{"
                        + pochhammer.group(2) + "}{" + pochhammer.group(3)
                        + "}");
                count--;
            }
            if(count==0)
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            }
    }
    public boolean checkMultiple(String line){
        Pattern cpochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\(([^\\)]+)\\)_\\{([^\\}]+)\\})");
        Matcher pochhammer = cpochhammer.matcher(line);
        if(pochhammer.find())
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        RealReadFile file = new RealReadFile();
        while (!file.endOfFile()) {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            Pattern cpochhammer = Pattern.compile("(\\(([^\\)]+)\\)_\\{?([^\\}]+)\\}?)");
            Matcher pochhammer = cpochhammer.matcher(line);
            StringBuffer rplcmntBfr = new StringBuffer();
            while(pochhammer.find())  {
               pochhammer.appendReplacement(rplcmntBfr, "\\\\pochhammer{" + pochhammer.group(2) + "}{" + pochhammer.group(3) + "}");
            }
            pochhammer.appendTail(rplcmntBfr);
            System.out.println(rplcmntBfr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just hand us a bunch of code and say "Whats wrong?".

Comment: Illegal group reference... it means you're trying to access something that doesn't exist. As an aside, why is there an absolute absence of try/catch statements? You should be able to handle these sorts of things with a degree of grace.

Comment: @Rick, I'm sorry, its just that I can't figure out what might be causing the problem.

Comment: @arco444 It doesn't make sense though, because the exception only comes up halfway after matching and replacing half of the file already. And if the groups didn't exist, it probably wouldn't have matched the pattern. And I will try to use the try-catch statements now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hypothesis: somewhere in your matching groups, there is a valid group reference in the form `"$n"` where `n` cannot match any group in the original `Pattern`.

Hence the error: "illegal group reference".

Solution: use `"$2"` instead of concatenating `.group(2)` etc.

Ie instead of writing:

```
"\\\\pochhammer{"+ pochhammer.group(2) + "}{" + pochhammer.group(3) + "}"
```

write:

```
"\\\\pochhammer{$2}{$3}"
```

Side note: no need to escape parens in a character class; `[^)]` works just as well as `[^\)]`, and it is easier to read ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a special character in `java.lang.String.replaceFirst` Method.

You should turn `$` into `\\$`.

You can get the result from http://www.onstepr.com/posts/51

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.